# In-App billing service is unavailable on some devices

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using in-app billing purchase in my application. below is the code that i have used make Request Bundle.

```
protected Bundle makeRequestBundle(String method) {
Bundle request = new Bundle();
request.putString(BILLING_REQUEST, method);
request.putInt(API_VERSION, 1);
request.putString(PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
return request;
}
```

And below is the code i used for purchase request.

```
  Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
  Integer responseCodeIndex     = (Integer) response.get("RESPONSE_CODE");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = (PendingIntent)       
  response.get("PURCHASE_INTENT");
  PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = (PendingIntent) response.get("BUY_INTENT");
  Long requestIndentifier   = (Long) response.get("REQUEST_ID");
  BillingConstants.ResponseCode responseCode =       
  BillingConstants.ResponseCode.valueOf(responseCodeIndex);
  Log.i(TAG, "REQUEST_PURCHASE Sync Response code: "+responseCode.toString());
```

This code gives error, service is not available on Android 5.0